# jquery function return json value in array

Tags: jquery, json, function, return

I would make a jquery function that import a json value and return an array when we call it. 
I coded the following function but the returned array is empty.

The json file is very basic like this example :

```
{
"fruit": [ "babana", "pineapple", "apple" ],
"vegetable" :  [ "salad", "carrot", "tomato" ]
}
```

I call my json with the following function

```
$( function() {
var fruit = new Array();
var vegetable = new Array();
var food = new Array();

function loadJson(result) {
    $.getJSON('myfile.json', function (data) {
        fruit = data.fruit;
        vegetable = data.vegetable;
    })
    .error(function() {
        console.log('error: JSON not loaded');
    })
    .done(function() {
        //console.log( "JSON loaded!" );
        var food = fruit.concat(vegetable);
        return result;
    });
}
```

After I call this function in another function with

```
loadJson(food);   loadJson(fruit);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: i think you need to make  var result = fruit.concat(vegetable); and then 
        return result;

Comment: @Andreas thanks, yes it look as asynchronous call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, I've fired mine on document ready just so I could test the function quickly, but you should give you the result you're after.

Answer Updated:

```
function loadJson( type ) {

var final_result = null;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "test.json",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var fruit = data['fruit'],
                vegetable = data['vegetable'],
                food = fruit.concat(vegetable),
                result = food;

            switch( type ) {
                case 'fruit':
                    result = fruit;
                    break;
                case 'vegetable':
                    result = vegetable;
                    break;
                case 'food':
                    result = food;
                    break;
            }
            final_result = result;
        }
    });
    return final_result;
}


$( document ).ready(function() {
    loadJson( 'food' );
    loadJson( 'fruit' );
    loadJson( 'vegetable' );

    var test = loadJson( 'fruit' );
    console.log( test );
 });
```

Comment: Thanks you for you help.
But if I add in document ready function 
`var test = loadJson( 'food' ); ` 
`console.log(test) ;` 
it's return undefined

Comment: Hi @julienchips, please check out the updated answer.